# expand script in Maya/Python

Tags: python, maya

i´m working with the jlcollisiondeformer and i´m very new to python in maya.

http://wtp-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Library/maya/python/misc/jlCollisionDeformer/jlCollisionDeformer.py

In this script you have to select the collidermesh followed by the mesh that should be deformed and then run a MEL command to run the script. This is a bit cumbersome...

Does anyone know how to expand the script to a plugin that shows a simple window with three buttons like "Set as 'collidermesh'", "Set as 'to be deformed mesh'" and "run CollisionDeformer"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to modify the script yourself?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty standard maya behaviour. If you want to have a button to do it you can type

jlCollisionDeformer();

into the script listener and middle-mouse drag it into a shelf button. That will call the procedure on the current selection. You *could* modify the mel script to take explicit parameters (that would be a good idea over the long run since it's more explicit) but it's such a simple behaviour to script (select source, select target) that it seems like a waste of effort.

In python it's a teensy bit more work but it would look like this:

```
import maya.mel
import maya.cmds as cmds

def  CollisionDeform(source, target):
    cmds.select(source, target)
    maya.mel.eval("jlCollisionDeformer()");
```

Then any script you want could call CollisionDeform on two objects to get the deformer to work.  You'd need to write the UI that selects the objects and calls the functions though.

I suspect the shelf button is the easy way to go.  You can also add a hotkey in the hotkey editor:

[image]